# Using bash variable in text output

Tags: bash, variables, imagemagick-convert

I'm using convert to add text to some images via a bash script.  My issue is that I can't figure out how to add the contents of the variable to the text string to be placed in the image.

**My script is as follows:**

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
    convert -font TlwgTypewriter-Bold -pointsize 18 -fill white -draw 'text 140,29 "ID: $i"' $i.png $i-reward.png
done
```

But when I run it I get the following:

[image: bashimage]

How might I get the variable to output its contents into this string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it is due to wrong quoting of your command here:

```
-draw 'text 140,29 "ID: $i"'
```

Change that to:

```
-draw "text 140,29 \"ID: $i\""
```

It is because shell doesn't expand variables inside single quote.